# Which number on the rear of an original release PS2 is the proper serial number?

Tags: ps2

A PS2 contains two unique identifiers on its rear sticker. A number labeled "SERIAL" to the left, and a barcode sticker offset to the right, with different characters in each.

[image: Rear of a PlayStation 2]

This random PS2 from an internet screenshot has a "serial" of "AU43211911", and a "barcode" of "PX443219113".

If I am cataloging a PS2 for asset tracking, collecting, grading, or any other purpose, which of these numbers would I use to represent its identity and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The actual SERIAL.**

As the name says, the unique serial number in this case is AU43211911. The barcode is more of an inventory control tool.

Funnily enough, this also happens with the PS3. I have a CECH-3011A Slim console with a barcode under the console that is different than the Serial Number on the rear.